# How can I plot these values more clearly? (jagged line graph)

Tags: r, plotly

I have a dataset that looks similar to this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(X = c("5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", 
"35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", 
"46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", 
"57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", 
"68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", 
"79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", 
"90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", 
"137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", 
"146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", 
"155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", 
"164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", 
"173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", 
"182", "183", "184", "Showing 83 to 101 of 440 entries, 5 total columns"
), Date_Time = c("2021-01-06 08:13:00", "2021-01-06 08:14:00", 
"2021-01-06 08:15:00", "2021-01-06 08:16:00", "2021-01-06 08:17:00", 
"2021-01-06 08:18:00", "2021-01-06 08:19:00", "2021-01-06 08:20:00", 
"2021-01-06 08:21:00", "2021-01-06 08:22:00", "2021-01-06 08:23:00", 
"2021-01-06 08:24:00", "2021-01-06 08:25:00", "2021-01-06 08:26:00", 
"2021-01-06 08:27:00", "2021-01-06 08:28:00", "2021-01-06 08:41:00", 
"2021-01-06 08:42:00", "2021-01-06 08:43:00", "2021-01-06 08:44:00", 
"2021-01-06 08:45:00", "2021-01-06 08:46:00", "2021-01-06 08:54:00", 
"2021-01-06 08:59:00", "2021-01-06 09:00:00", "2021-01-06 09:01:00", 
"2021-01-06 09:02:00", "2021-01-06 09:03:00", "2021-01-06 09:04:00", 
"2021-01-06 09:33:00", "2021-01-06 09:34:00", "2021-01-06 09:35:00", 
"2021-01-06 09:36:00", "2021-01-06 09:37:00", "2021-01-06 09:38:00", 
"2021-01-04 14:01:00", "2021-01-04 13:31:00", "2021-01-04 13:32:00", 
"2021-01-04 13:33:00", "2021-01-04 13:34:00", "2021-01-04 13:35:00", 
"2021-01-04 13:36:00", "2021-01-04 13:37:00", "2021-01-04 13:38:00", 
"2021-01-04 13:39:00", "2021-01-04 13:40:00", "2021-01-04 13:41:00", 
"2021-01-04 13:42:00", "2021-01-04 13:43:00", "2021-01-04 13:44:00", 
"2021-01-04 13:45:00", "2021-01-04 13:46:00", "2021-01-04 13:49:00", 
"2021-01-04 13:50:00", "2021-01-04 13:51:00", "2021-01-04 13:52:00", 
"2021-01-04 13:53:00", "2021-01-04 13:54:00", "2021-01-04 13:55:00", 
"2021-01-05 13:02:00", "2021-01-04 07:54:00", "2021-01-03 20:23:00", 
"2021-01-03 20:25:00", "2021-01-03 20:27:00", "2021-01-01 13:33:00", 
"2021-01-01 13:35:00", "2021-01-01 13:36:00", "2021-01-01 13:37:00", 
"2021-01-01 13:38:00", "2021-01-01 18:01:00", "2021-01-06 07:43:00", 
"2021-01-06 07:45:00", "2021-01-06 07:46:00", "2021-01-06 07:48:00", 
"2021-01-06 07:49:00", "2021-01-06 07:50:00", "2021-01-05 11:56:00", 
"2021-01-05 11:56:00", "2021-01-01 18:09:00", "2021-01-01 18:10:00", 
"2021-01-01 18:11:00", "2021-01-01 18:12:00", "2021-01-04 10:28:00", 
"2021-01-04 10:29:00", "2021-01-04 10:30:00", "2021-01-06 17:18:00", 
"2021-01-06 14:15:00", "2021-01-02 14:26:00", "2021-01-04 07:49:00", 
"2021-01-04 07:50:00", "2021-01-04 07:51:00", "2021-01-04 08:04:00", 
"2021-01-04 08:19:00", "2021-01-04 11:39:00", "2021-01-02 12:49:00", 
"2021-01-02 12:50:00", "2021-01-02 12:51:00", "2021-01-02 12:52:00", 
"2021-01-02 12:53:00", "2021-01-02 12:54:00", "2021-01-02 12:55:00", 
"2021-01-02 12:56:00", "2021-01-02 12:57:00", "2021-01-02 12:58:00", 
"2021-01-02 12:59:00", "2021-01-02 13:00:00", "2021-01-02 13:01:00", 
"2021-01-02 13:02:00", "2021-01-02 13:12:00", "2021-01-02 13:13:00", 
"2021-01-02 13:14:00", "2021-01-02 13:15:00", "2021-01-02 13:16:00", 
"2021-01-02 13:17:00", "2021-01-02 13:18:00", "2021-01-04 08:32:00", 
"2021-01-06 12:08:00", "2021-01-06 12:13:00", "2021-01-06 12:14:00", 
"2021-01-06 12:15:00", "2021-01-06 12:16:00", "2021-01-06 12:17:00", 
"2021-01-06 12:18:00", "2021-01-05 10:11:00", "2021-01-05 10:12:00", 
"2021-01-05 10:13:00", "2021-01-02 09:22:00", "2021-01-02 09:25:00", 
"2021-01-02 09:26:00", "2021-01-02 09:27:00", "2021-01-02 09:28:00", 
"2021-01-02 09:29:00", "2021-01-04 12:05:00", "2021-01-04 12:06:00", 
"2021-01-04 12:07:00", "2021-01-04 12:08:00", "2021-01-04 12:09:00", 
"2021-01-04 12:18:00", "2021-01-06 07:35:00", "2021-01-06 07:36:00", 
"2021-01-06 07:37:00", "2021-01-06 07:38:00", "2021-01-06 07:39:00", 
"2021-01-06 07:40:00", "2021-01-06 07:41:00", "2021-01-06 07:42:00", 
"2021-01-06 07:51:00", "2021-01-06 07:52:00", "2021-01-06 07:54:00", 
"2021-01-02 07:32:00", "2021-01-02 07:35:00", "2021-01-03 13:08:00", 
"2021-01-04 13:08:00", "2021-01-02 16:19:00", "2021-01-02 16:22:00", 
"2021-01-02 16:25:00", "2021-01-02 16:26:00", "2021-01-02 16:30:00", 
"2021-01-02 16:32:00", "2021-01-02 16:35:00", "2021-01-02 16:37:00", 
"2021-01-02 16:38:00", "2021-01-02 07:52:00", "2021-01-02 07:53:00", 
"2021-01-02 07:54:00", "2021-01-02 07:55:00", "2021-01-02 10:33:00", 
"2021-01-02 10:34:00", "2021-01-02 10:35:00", "2021-01-02 10:36:00", 
"2021-01-02 12:06:00", "2021-01-02 12:09:00", "2021-01-02 07:35:00", 
"2021-01-01 10:30:00", "2021-01-01 10:31:00", "2021-01-01 10:32:00", 
"2021-01-01 10:33:00", "2021-01-01 10:34:00", "2021-01-01 10:35:00", 
"2021-01-01 10:36:00", ""), Chemical_x = c("Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", 
"Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", "Benzene", ""), Value_X = c(1.6, 
1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 
1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.9, 1.9, 1.6, 1.7, 
1.7, 1.8, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 2.2, 3.4, 4.1, 4.6, 5.2, 
5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 6, 6.5, 4.7, 3.3, 3.6, 3.8, 3.6, 3.3, 3.3, 2.3, 
2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 1.9, 1.8, 1.8, 1.9, 1.4, 1.9, 1.9, 1.6, 1.7, 1.5, 
2, 2.2, 2.2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1.5, 2.1, 2.1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.8, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 
1.4, 2.2, 1.6, 1.8, 1.7, 1.7, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 2, 1.7, 1.8, 
1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 1.6, 1.9, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 4.1, 3.7, 3.3, 3.6, 6.7, 5.6, 5.3, 5.9, 
4.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 1.4, 4.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 3.4, 3, 
2.8, 2.8, 4.6, 4.4, 3.9, 1.4, 1.5, 1.7, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.4, 
1.8, 1.8, 1.6, 1.4, 1.5, 2.1, 1.7, 2, 1.9, 1.6, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 
1.7, 1.6, 1.7, 6.3, 4.7, 5.1, 4.4, 3.8, 3.8, 3.9, NA), Chemical_y = c("Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", 
"Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", "Propene", ""), Value_y = c(10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0.5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 8.7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 
9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8.65, 
10, 9.15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9.2, 9.2, 9.2, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 9.2, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8.9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 9.9, 9.9, 
9.9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9.49, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9.02, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8.9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -181L), class = "data.frame")
```

But when I plot the values, I get a graph that looks like this (somewhat jagged):
[image]

My concern is that, with the larger/real dataset, it looks even **more** jagged
[image: Used with Real Dataset]

Is there a better way to plot these values to get rid of the jagged lines and make it look like an actual cleaner version of a time-series plot?

Here is my code to create the plot:

```
fig <- plot_ly(df, type = 'scatter',
               mode = 'lines')%>%
  add_trace(x = ~Date_Time, y = ~Value_X, name = 'Benzene') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Date_Time, y = ~Value_y, name = 'Propene')
  
fig <- fig %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(zerolinecolor = '#ffff',
                 zerolinewidth = 2,
                 gridcolor = 'ffff'),
    yaxis = list(zerolinecolor = '#ffff',
                 zerolinewidth = 2,
                 gridcolor = 'ffff'),
    plot_bgcolor='#e5ecf6')


fig
```

Comment: Have you tried ordering the data before plotting?

Comment: It might benefit from converting your `Date_Time` variable to a timestamp (`POSIXt` class). (They are just strings right now, a categorical variable. I know R is not inferring timestamps from them, I'm guessing plotly is not as well.)

Comment: Ordering the dates helped, thank you so much! I initially thought the times were ordered, but I guess they weren't. Thank you again!